# How do you search for a string in a rich text box and highlight all found or highlight each line?

Tags: c#, listbox, richtextbox

I found the following code http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=146 and implemented it into my app, however it only finds the string once and to continue looking for other instances of the string you have to keep pressing the search button (bit tedious with 100's of matches).

I'd like to find all instances of the search string and if possible highlight each line, failing that highlight the string item like this code already does but all instances not just one.

On the link above there is possibly a solution down further on the page but it's in VB which I don't know how to convert to C#.

```
private void btnListSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int startindex = 0;
        if (txtSearch.Text.Length > 0)
            startindex = FindMyText(txtSearch.Text.Trim(), start, rtb.Text.Length);
        // If string was found in the RichTextBox, highlight it
        if (startindex >= 0)
        {
            // Set the highlight color as red
            rtb.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
            // Find the end index. End Index = number of characters in textbox
            int endindex = txtSearch.Text.Length;
            // Highlight the search string
            rtb.Focus();
            rtb.Select(startindex, endindex);
            // mark the start position after the position of 
            // last search string
            start = startindex + endindex;
        }
    }

    public int FindMyText(string txtToSearch, int searchStart, int searchEnd)
    {
        // Unselect the previously searched string
        if (searchStart > 0 && searchEnd > 0 && indexOfSearchText >= 0)
        {
            rtb.Undo();
        }
        // Set the return value to -1 by default.
        int retVal = -1;
        // A valid starting index should be specified.
        // if indexOfSearchText = -1, the end of search
        if (searchStart >= 0 && indexOfSearchText >=0)
        {
            // A valid ending index 
            if (searchEnd > searchStart || searchEnd == -1)
            {
                // Find the position of search string in RichTextBox
                indexOfSearchText = rtb.Find(txtToSearch, searchStart, searchEnd, RichTextBoxFinds.None);
                // Determine whether the text was found in richTextBox1.
                if (indexOfSearchText != -1)
                {
                    // Return the index to the specified search text.
                    retVal = indexOfSearchText;
                }
            }
        }
        return retVal;
    }

    private void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    // Reset the richtextbox when user changes the search string
        start = 0;
        indexOfSearchText = 0;
    }
```

I also tried to search a listbox but it would only find strings at the start of a line not along the line.

```
string searchString = textBox2.Text;
        listBoxResults.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiExtended;
        // Set our intial index variable to -1.
        int x = -1;
        // If the search string is empty exit.
        if (searchString.Length != 0)
        {
            // Loop through and find each item that matches the search string.
            do
            {
                // Retrieve the item based on the previous index found. Starts with -1 which searches start.
                x = listBoxResults.FindString(searchString, x);
                // If no item is found that matches exit.
                if (x != -1)
                {
                    // Since the FindString loops infinitely, determine if we found first item again and exit.
                    if (listBoxResults.SelectedIndices.Count > 0)
                    {
                        if (x == listBoxResults.SelectedIndices[0])
                            return;
                    }
                    // Select the item in the ListBox once it is found.
                    listBoxResults.SetSelected(x, true);
                }

            } while (x != -1);
        }
```

Comment: please indent the code correctly for better readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has a few problems.

- You call the search and selection routines only once per button click, so only one occurrence can be found each time.  If you want to highlight all occurrences you need to create a loop
- You undo each change in the `FindMyText` method. That makes no sense. You may want to clear all selections **before** you search something new, but not while searching
- You set the selection color before setting the selection. This will do nothing, at best..

Here is a version which stores all positions in a list and supports two buttons to go forward and backward through the list..:

```
List<int> found = null;

private void cb_findAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int cursorPos = rtb.SelectionStart; 
    clearHighlights(rtb);
    found = FindAll(rtb, txtSearch.Text, 0);
    HighlightAll(rtb, Color.Red, found, txtSearch.Text.Length);
    rtb.Select(cursorPos, 0);   
}

private void cb_findNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int pos = -1;
    for (int f = 0; f < found.Count; f++)
        if (found[f] > rtb.SelectionStart) { pos = found[f]; break; }
    if (pos >= 0) rtb.Select(pos, txtSearch.Text.Length);
    rtb.ScrollToCaret();
}

private void cb_findPrev_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int pos = -1;
    for (int f = 0; f < found.Count; f++)
        if (found[f] >= rtb.SelectionStart) { if (f >= 1) pos = found[f - 1]; break; }
    if (pos >= 0) rtb.Select(pos, txtSearch.Text.Length);
    rtb.ScrollToCaret();
}

public List<int> FindAll(RichTextBox rtb, string txtToSearch, int searchStart)
{
    List<int> found = new List<int>();
    if (txtToSearch.Length <= 0) return found;

    int pos= rtb.Find( txtToSearch, searchStart, RichTextBoxFinds.None);
    while (pos >= 0)
    {
        found.Add(pos);
        pos = rtb.Find(txtToSearch, pos + txtToSearch.Length, RichTextBoxFinds.None);
    }
    return found;
}

public void HighlightAll(RichTextBox rtb, Color color, List<int> found, int length)
{
    foreach (int p in found)
    {
        rtb.Select(p, length);
        rtb.SelectionColor = color;
    }
}

void clearHighlights(RichTextBox rtb)
{
    int cursorPos = rtb.SelectionStart;    // store cursor
    rtb.Select(0, rtb.TextLength);         // select all
    rtb.SelectionColor = rtb.ForeColor;    // default text color
    rtb.Select(cursorPos, 0);              // reset cursor
}


private void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    found = new List<int>();         // clear list
    clearHighlights(rtb);            // clear highlights
}
private void rtb_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    found = new List<int>();
    clearHighlights(rtb);
}
```

Note how small each piece of code is!

Comment: Hi TaW I'm getting this error with the above on this bit rtb.Select(startindex , 0); InvalidArgument=Value of '-1' is not valid for 'start'. Parameter name: start

Comment: Whoops, a typo.. see my corrected answer! I reset the cursor to a stored value now..

Comment: So close now, if I search for something then change the search criteria is doesn't search again until I clear the text box click search and then enter a string to search and click the button again. Perhaps it needs this back ? // Reset the richtextbox when user changes the search string
        start = 0;
        indexOfSearchText = 0;

Comment: No. It needs resetting the start variable in the click - see the corrected answer! I'm sleeping atm, though. I'll cleanup the whole code in the morning..

Comment: Thanks TaW, I'm wondering if there is only one result of a search string that it should stop at that string and highlight it, at the moment it it scrolls to the end of the rich text box and you have to scroll back up to find the highlighted text, Let me know your thoughts about the best option. What about a next and back button, I may have to send some $$ your way after this :-)

Comment: I have revised the code and added code for two extra buttons.. No need for $ or €, a checkmark will do..

Comment: Hi TaW, looking good, however the next button isn't working. I'll also add some message boxes to catch the user clicking the buttons with no text. Perhaps mention where List<int> found = null; sits (class level?) and there is an error because this was missing int cursorPos = -1; I'm very close to pressing the big tick ;-)

Comment: Yes the found list sits at class level. See the tiny correction ` if (found[f] > rtb.SelectionStart)` to make the next button work.. Ha, I had an old cursorpos at class level, not needed now, which hid the missing `int` in the `clearHighlights`, now also corrected.

Comment: The next button doesn't work unless you click previous a few times, because the cursor is at the bottom of the rich text box.

Comment: That's right. With the two extra lines in the `cb_findAll_Click` it should put the cursor the the right ie previous position..

Comment: Slight problem with the previous button, if you click next a few times then press previous to go back to the top it won't go to the first record but sticks on the 2nd record.

Comment: Yes. Your testing is a lot more thorough than minee.. There was an equal sign missing: `if (f >= 1)`. I added an optional clear for thr rtb's textchanged..

Comment: I've added these lines rtb.SelectionStart = 0; and rtb.ScrollToCaret(); to cb_findAll. Instead of rtb.Select(cursorPos, 0); after searching and highlighting the text you're looking for it ends up back at the top of the rtb, then when next is clicked it immediately goes to the first highlighted text. Many thanks for all your help TaW.