# C# richbox change color

Tags: c#, richtextbox

```
    string words;
    private void Colors(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Color tags = new Color();
        tags = Color.FromArgb(33, 66, 99);
    }
    private Color FromRgbExample()
    {
        // Create a green color using the FromRgb static method.
        Color myRgbColor = new Color();
        myRgbColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 0);
        return myRgbColor;
    }
    private void CheckKeyword(string word, Color color, int startIndex)
    {
        words = word;
        if (this.richTextBox1.Text.Contains(word))
        {
            int index = -1;
            int selectStart = this.richTextBox1.SelectionStart;

            while ((index = this.richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(word, (index + 1))) != -1)
            {

                this.richTextBox1.Select((index + startIndex), word.Length);
                this.richTextBox1.SelectionColor = color;
                this.richTextBox1.Select(selectStart, 0);
                this.richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Black;
            }
        }
    }
    private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 

        this.CheckKeyword("html", Color.Green, 0);
        this.CheckKeyword("head", Color.Green, 0);

        if (richTextBox1.Text.Contains(words) == false)
        {
            this.richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Black;
        }
    }


}
```

If i write "html" text will have green color, if i delete any letter from "html" he will still be with green color.
How i can do after deleting a letter to change "html" color back to black?

Comment: You will need to re-do __all__ the checks & and the coloring whenever you change the text. This means make it all black and then re-color. Maybe you can optimize but since a TextChanged may be about a single letter or whole paragraphs beind insert or deleted this will not be trivial..

Comment: Colors was just a test, i want to know how to do that                                                      if (richTextBox1.Text.Contains(words) == false)
        {
            this.richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Black;
        }

Comment: Well that is how to do that, but you also need to actually select the portion of text you want to color. Best write a function that finds all keywords and colors them. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26530443/how-do-you-search-for-a-string-in-a-rich-text-box-and-highlight-all-found-or-hig/26533012#26533012) for an example..

Answer (score 0):

```
private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    richTextBox1.Select(0,richTextBox1.Text.Length -1);
    richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Black;
    richTextBox1.SelectionStart = 0;

    this.CheckKeyword("html", Color.Green, 0);
    this.CheckKeyword("head", Color.Green, 0);

    if (richTextBox1.Text.Contains(words) == false)
    {
        this.richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Black;
    }
}
```